# Hartl's Tutorial Ch13 - unable to deploy to Heroku after configuring carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku

Ch 13.4.4 from Hartl's tutorial on "Image upload in production".

When trying to deploy to heroku, I get the following error:

```
Counting objects: 63, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 12.81 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 63 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Using rake 11.3.0
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using minitest 5.9.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Using rack 2.0.1
remote:        Using nio4r 1.2.1
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using arel 7.1.3
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing CFPropertyList 2.3.3
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.11
remote:        Using sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using will_paginate 3.1.0
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Using method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing excon 0.53.0
remote:        Installing json 2.0.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mimemagic 0.3.2
remote:        Installing formatador 0.2.5
remote:        Using multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Installing xml-simple 1.1.5
remote:        Installing ipaddress 0.8.3
remote:        Installing trollop 2.1.2
remote:        Installing inflecto 0.0.2
remote:        Using pg 0.18.4
remote:        Installing mini_magick 4.5.1
remote:        Using puma 3.4.0
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Using faker 1.6.6
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.8.1
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.0
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.6.4
remote:        Using mime-types 3.1
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 6.5.0.2
remote:        Using uglifier 3.0.0
remote:        Using bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.10
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing fog-core 1.43.0
remote:        Installing fission 0.5.0
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Using activesupport 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
remote:        Installing rbvmomi 1.8.2
remote:        Installing fog-json 1.0.2
remote:        Installing fog-xml 0.1.2
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.1
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.7
remote:        Using activemodel 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.4.1
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Installing fog-local 0.3.0
remote:        Installing fog-vmfusion 0.1.0
remote:        Installing fog-brightbox 0.11.0
remote:        Installing fog-openstack 0.1.15
remote:        Installing fog-aliyun 0.1.0
remote:        Installing fog-profitbricks 2.0.1
remote:        Installing fog-sakuracloud 1.7.5
remote:        Installing fog-serverlove 0.1.2
remote:        Installing fog-softlayer 1.1.4
remote:        Installing fog-storm_on_demand 0.1.1
remote:        Installing fog-atmos 0.1.0
remote:        Installing fog-cloudatcost 0.1.2
remote:        Installing fog-aws 0.12.0
remote:        Installing fog-dynect 0.0.3
remote:        Installing fog-ecloud 0.3.0
remote:        Installing fog-google 0.1.0
remote:        Installing fog-powerdns 0.1.1
remote:        Installing fog-radosgw 0.0.5
remote:        Installing fog-rackspace 0.1.1
remote:        Installing fog-riakcs 0.1.0
remote:        Installing fog-voxel 0.1.0
remote:        Installing fog-terremark 0.1.0
remote:        Installing fog-vsphere 1.2.1
remote:        Installing fog-xenserver 0.2.3
remote:        Using activejob 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using activerecord 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using actionview 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using actionpack 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using actioncable 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using railties 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using rails 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Installing carrierwave 0.11.2
remote:        Installing fog 1.38.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 28 Gemfile dependencies, 100 gems now installed
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (8.97s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in `validate_options'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:268:in `handle_settings'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/core/services_mixin.rb:16:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fog-core-1.43.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:27:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/carrierwave-0.11.2/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/config/initializers/carrier_wave.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:448:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_d6e56f1586e33307e3549a279f377845/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to octopus-sample-app.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/octopus-sample-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/octopus-sample-app.git'
```

My carrer_wave.rb looks like this:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider              => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region                => ENV['S3_REGION']
    }
    config.fog_directory     = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

And I'm sure I've configured the AWS access key, secret key, region and bucket properly, which I've confirmed by looking under config vars in the Heroku app.

Comment: are you sure your Heroku is running in production mode? check it out under settings-> config vars-> RAILS_ENV

Comment: When you have created your account did you set the good region too?

Comment: Heroku definitely in production mode. I created a bucket and set it to oregon region. Then typed `heroku config:set S3_REGION=us-west-2`